# Unable to register VB dll created in 32 bit in 64 bit Windows 7 Machine

Tags: asp.net, windows, com

Unable to register VB dll created in 32 bit in 64 bit Windows 7 Machine. getting the below error. and also not able to give reference to my dot net project

Thanks,
Pradeep

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 32 bit version of regsvr32.  For example:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe /i "C:\New Folder\M2MJOMastAPI_601.dll"
```

What's more, if you have UAC enabled, then you will need to run regsvr32 as an elevated process.  I generally do this by running the Command Prompt as Administrator (right click on the shortcut and select Run as Administrator) and then executing the 32 bit regsvr32 from there.